# How to fetch data inside </br> tag which is inside <li> using python scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="row features_2 "><br />
        <ul>

                    <li><b>Área privada:</b><br />
                    70,00 m²
                    </li>

            <!--area-->

                    <li><b>Área Const.:</b><br />
                    70,00 m²
                    </li>

            <!--precio metro cuadrado-->

                <li><b>Precio m²:</b><br />
                3.142.857/m²
                </li>

            <!--Valor noche si es alquiler vacacional-->

            <!--precio de administracion -->

                    <li><b>Admón:</b><br />
                    $150,000</li>

            <!--Estrato si aplica-->

                <li><b>Estrato:</b> <br />
                3

            <!--Estado si aplica-->

                <li><b>Estado:</b> <br />
                    Excelente
                </li>

            <!--edad si aplica-->

                <li><b>Antigüedad:</b> <br />
                1 a 8 años</li>

            <!--piso #-->

            <!--Clima-->

            <!--tipo de apartamento si aplica-->

            <!--para parqueaderos-->
            <!--caracteristicas parqueadero-->

            <!--Sector (siempre va)-->
            <li><b>Sector:</b> <br />

                <a href="#pnlMap" style="font-weight: bold;">Ver Mapa</a>

            </li>  


        </ul>
```

From the above I'd like to get the values inside  tag, however I'm having trouble in saving the values to individual list.

I'd like to save the values based on the data inside the  itself.

For example if the  tag contains 'Área privada:', then I've to save the value '70,00 m²' to list name area

else if  tag contains 'Precio m²:' , then I've to save the value 3.142.857/m² into list named Precio

I've tried the following code to get the elements, but not sure how to write the condition the save the data into list based on above condition.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/oceana-52/barranquilla/proyecto-nuevo-det-1041165.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
box_3 = soup.find('div' ,'row features_2 ')
box_3_1  = box_3.findAll('li')
for i in box_3_1:
    print (i)
```

Else is there any other option to save the data from the above tag to respective lists.

Comment: `br` tags don't contain any data..

Comment: The html looks so confusing.

Comment: so only added the python code to get the html element from the web page

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) property of `<br>`:

```
for li in box_3_1:
    print(str(li.br.next_sibling).strip())
```

Output:

```
71,00 a 185,00 m²
78,00 a 207,00 m²
5
Cálido
```

OP wanted to store "Área" and "Precio" data in separate lists.  Assuming those two strings never appear in the same `<li>` heading, here's a full solution:

```
area = []
precio = []
for li in box_3_1:
    heading_words = li.b.text.split()
    target_content = str(li.br.next_sibling).strip()
    if "Área" in heading_words:
        area.append(target_content)
    elif "Precio" in heading_words:
        precio.append(target_content)
```

For a more general solution, consider making a list of key header terms, and then storing all output in a dict.  For example:

```
import re

key_terms = ["Área", "Precio", "Estrato"]
data = {k:[] for k in key_terms}

for li in box_3_1:
    heading = li.b.text
    target_content = str(li.br.next_sibling).strip()
    for term in key_terms:
        # Headers like "Estrato:" do not match on split() due to end ":"; use re instead.
        if re.search(term, heading):
            data[term].append(target_content)          
data
{'Estrato': ['5'],
 'Precio': [],
 'Área': ['71,00 a 185,00 m²', '78,00 a 207,00 m²']}
```

Comment: So you could also use a dictionary (or a list of dicts if you're going for more than 1 item) to store  your stuff. If you do a soup.find_all('li') it should hold both value and key separeted by a colon. If you loop through results (remember to strip ekstra whitespaces and all), and do a .text.split(':'), you'd then have the key at index 0 and value at index 1. So if you had a result_dict, you'd just insert those like so result_dict[your_list[0]] = your_list[1].

Comment: Thanks, I used a modified version of your suggestion in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you andrew_reece, it works very well for me, I'm delighted with your support for me in this issue

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer resolved your issue, please mark it accepted by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.